# Jax-RS : Getting error message from REST call?

Tags: java, rest, error-handling, jax-rs, postman

I am using `Jax-RS` as my `REST` framework. I want to be able to pull out the error message from the rest call if it fails (i.e. with a 500 error). What is the best way to do so?

E.g. when I make my call in `POSTMAN` and get an error I get the following with the 500:

```
{
    "reason": "No data retrieved for GET call",
    "response": "failure"
}
```

How can I retrieve this information in my code, in the case that the call fails?

Comment: what do you mean how do you retrieve the code? Parse the json and read the reason?

Comment: I am getting a 500 error before this, I will edit my question now

Comment: please edit and post sample too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're looking for is to parse that:

That response is in a text format called `JSON` (JavaScript Object Notation)

Use a `JSON` parsing library such as [GSON](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.2)

```
String json = //..... get the api response as a String ....
APIResponse response = new Gson().fromJson(json, APIResponse.class);
```

Using an `ApiResponse` looking like:

```
public class APIResponse {

    public String reason;
    public String response;

    public void setReason(String reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
    }

    public String getReason() {
        return this.reason;
    }

    public void setReason(String reason) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        return this.response;
    }
}
```

---

On the other hand if that is the response coming from your API and you are looking to handle it: have a look at [JAX-RS Exception Handling](https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-2rd-edition/en/part1/chapter7/exception_handling.html#exception-mapping)

You can implement the `ExceptionMapper` interface:

```
public interface ExceptionMapper<E extends Throwable> {
   Response toResponse(E exception);
}
```

and register a `@Provider` that handles the exception:

```
@Provider
public class EntityNotFoundMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {

   public Response toResponse(Exception e) {
      // Do some logic like log an error
      return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
   }
}
```